# redirect to https folder in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl, https

I was trying to get an entire directory/section of my website to automatically re-direct to https (secure) using the .htaccess file, so I found a solution on here. It turns out it re-directs my **ENTIRE** site to HTTPS except for the homepage. I'd like it to only re-direct the /php/ folder and anything inside it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is my code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://beanstalkwebsolutions.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^php(/|$) https://beanstalkwebsolutions.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R,L]
```